# In Xcode, How Can I Add A Tutorial Window to My Mac App, Which Opens Only On First Launch

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm designing a MacOS app, for which I'd like to have a second window appear on the first time the app is launched (similar to what Apple does on the first time you open iMovie or Pages). I've tried a couple things to no avail. So far, I've created a second group as a target of the original app. The new group contains the tutorial storyboard I designed and a custom class called OnboardingWindowController (a subclass of NSWindowController). I gave the window controller the Storyboard ID of OnboardingWindowController, and added the following method:

```
class func loadFromNib() -> OnboardingWindowController {
        let vc = NSStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "OnboardingWindowController") as! OnboardingWindowController
        return vc
    }
```

I'm not sure, however, how to get this to launch without prompting the first time the app is launched and then never again. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add a key to userdefaults check it's value, if it's false then show the tutorial else don't.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didShowTutorial") {
    // Code to proceed without showing tutorial
} else {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didShowTutorial")
    // Code to show the tutorial
}
```

Comment: Wasn't really where my problem was, but I got it working anyway. And thanks for the effort.